# Accessing shares on a workgroup from a domain

Tags: domain, network-share, file-permissions, workgroup

hopefully someone can help me out here (I've searched, but have come up empty so far).

My client PC (Win7) is a member of a large domain.  I have a separate workgroup of 4 computers, one of which is a Win 2008 server that I'm using to run IIS to host an internal webapp.  I tried setting up a share on the C:\inetpub\wwwroot folder, which works (it's called 'iis'), but I can't access it from the client computer on the domain when I try to located \serverip\iis.  Doesn't say invalid user or anything, it just says that it can't find it.

Under "Share and Storage Management" I have both the Share and NTFS permissions set so that "Everyone" has full access to the share (bad form, I know... just trying to get this to work first).  I've also remoted in and copied my files there, and I can access the webapp just fine through standard HTTP in a browser from my client, so the physical connection is fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a name resolution problem. Are the workgroup computers registered in your AD DNS?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I have admin privileges for the 2k8 server and the workgroup computers, but my client PC on the domain is just a standard user.  I'm not an admin on the domain.  I'm not sure it's a naming issue so much though, as I can ping it and see the webpage in browser from the server's IIS just fine and remote in, all from my client PC.

Comment: Also going to add here that I'm accessing the shares and the website using the server's IP address, not the hostname.

Comment: oops, my bad. I thought you were trying to access it by name. It looks like you're trying to access it by ip address, so name resolution wouldn't be an issue there.

Comment: Any firewalls between the machines, either software or hardware?

Comment: Only Windows firewall on each machine, no commercial software or hardware setups.  I can reach the machine just fine to communicate with it via it's IP address when I connect by browser (HTTP:80), or by using the Remote Connection.  It's only when I want to access a share that I get the problem.  The share itself is SMB, and shared with 'Everyone'. I even tried creating my duplicate account credentials on the workgroup server, and tried to connect to share with those credentials, as well as the admin login - no joy.